# Using boolean logic from a class to set off a timer if a condition is true

Tags: c#, winforms, boolean

So in my windows form I have a button that you click to start a timer, I only want the timer to start when the door is closed.

In my wm class I have

```
        public bool doorState()
    {
        if (doorClosed == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And in the main code I have

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (wm.doorState())
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
```

However when I press button 3 now the timer will not start regardless of whether the door is closed.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's not enough code to tell, btw you can simply return `doorClosed` in `doorState`.

Comment: Also,  even if you actually need the if block for some other purpose not mentioned, ==true is unnecessary

Comment: I see in your logic of `button3_Click` you have implemented case of `doorClosed` but not for `!doorClosed` (door is not closed). your code should run properly on first click of `button3`, but once you started the timer, as you are not stopping or disabling it. it will not have any change if you click `button3` while door is not closed (i.e if timer is already running, timer will not stop on button3 click even after door is not closed )

Answer (score 0):

Just set the timer to enabled to `true` or `false`

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (wm.doorState())
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }
    else
   {
      timer1.Enabled = false;
   }
}
```

And don't forget to set the timer `interval` to the properties like `Interval to 1000` if you want the tick for every second.

or you can set it in code behind like:

```
timer1.Interval = 1000;
```